# Retrieve only one row with dense_rank while using the avg analytic function

Tags: sql

I am not able to figure out how I would be able to retrieve only one row per dense_rank result while using the avg function. It would be in some way a group by of the result.

```
select 
         AVG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY hour) AS avg_price,
         dense_rank() over(order by hour)  as TheRank
         from table
         where transdate <= to_date('03032016', 'DDMMYYYY')
```

my result are as follow

```
avg_price    TheRank
10             1
10             1
12             2
12             2
15             3
15             3
```

I would Like

```
avg_price    TheRank
10             1
12             2
15             3
```

hopefully there is enough information to guide you.
Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: if you could provide some sample table data as well,there might be a way to get only the records you need

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle 12 Standard Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an aggregation with `dense_rank()` "afterwards":

```
select AVG(price) as avg_price,
       dense_rank() over (order by AVG(price)) as TheRank
from table
where transdate <= date '2016-03-03' -- remove `date` if you are not using Oracle
group by hour;
```

This assumes that you want to aggregate by hour, and then rank the prices by the average per hour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this suggestion pointed me toward my solution.

Answer (score 0):

After searching on the forum to build sample_date to provide more information, I found my solution

```
select 
         AVG(price) keep(dense_rank last order by PARTITION BY hour) AS avg_price
         from table
         where transdate <= to_date('03032016', 'DDMMYYYY')
```

Comment: The KEEP function qualifies an aggregate_function, indicating that only the FIRST or LAST values of aggregate_function will be returned. In my case It did not matter the first or last since all values were equal due to the average.